# PrepareForSegue method crashes app iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue, pushviewcontroller

I have a `UIButton` that, when I click on it, pushes another view controller, but it crashes here 
`textViewController.message = self.selectedMessage;` with error set message.

This is my button with code and method where it crashes:

```
- (IBAction)image:(id)sender {

   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"image" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showLogin"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
    } else {
        [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showImage"];
        [segue.destinationViewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
        ImageViewController *imageViewController = (ImageViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        imageViewController.message = self.selectedMessage;
    }
}
```

How can I fix the `PrepareForSegue` method so I can go to next VC when I press button. I put exception break point and it crashes at `imageViewController.message = self.selectedMessage;`. when I comment that line out everything works fine.

Comment: Are you sure the destinationViewController really is of type ImageViewController and not, for example, UINavigationController?

Comment: How can you be sure? If it crashes and the selector for message  property cannot be found then it is not ImageViewController.

Comment: see answer below for fix

Comment: post the complete crash log.

Comment: if the identifier is `image` why compare with `showImage`. Check your else is bad structured. Should be `else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"image"]){`. Please add complete crash log

Comment: print your `imageViewController` instance king class, and verify if is `ImageViewController`

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showLogin"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
    } else {
        ImageViewController *imageViewController = (ImageViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        [imageViewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
        imageViewController.message = self.selectedMessage;
    }
}
```

Try this .

Comment: not working this is error [ViewController setMessage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155f95e60

Comment: show me the message property of Imageviewcontroller. . . .the error is there @Joey121

Comment: How would removing one useless line prevent it from crashing? destinationViewController is not ImageViewController if the selector cannot be found.

Comment: Please check the segue  in storyboard you have created . . .it is not pointing to imageviewcontroller.Or Your Identifier for segue to imageviewcontroller is not set

Comment: see my answer blow for fix

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showLogin"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
    } else {
        [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showImage"];
        [segue.destinationViewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
        ImageViewController *imageViewController = (ImageViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        imageViewController.message = self.selectedMessage;
    }
}
```

had to change it to this for it to work

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showLogin"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showImage"]){
        [segue.destinationViewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
        ImageViewController *imageViewController = (ImageViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        imageViewController.message = self.selectedMessage;
    }
}
```